# WPF RichTextBox context menu language has different behaviour on different computers

Tags: c#, wpf, spell-checking

I've created a spell-checking `RichTextBox`, where I've set its language and the UI app language to Spanish:

```
   Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("es-ES");
   Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("es-ES");
   richTextBox.Language = XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name);
   richTextBox.SpellCheck.IsEnabled = true;
```

Use cases:

1. **WINDOWS 10**, region Spain: everything's in
   spanish (expected result, ok)
2. **WINDOWS 7**, region Spain: context menu (not that I've created, it's the default) is in English (which I don't know why). Also some words are marked here as wrong, even though they were marked as well spelled on the previous computer.

All the others elements (of my app) have their context menu in Spanish. The only one which is needed to be changed is the spellchecking `RichTextBox`.

Can anyone see what did I miss?

**Why context menu is in English and why some words are not well spelled on only windows 7 computer**?

Thank you!!!

Comment: It looks that something is still set in English. **Maybe** is being set (somewhere) after you have set the CurrentCultureUI to Spanish. Could you try to check when the spell check is being carried out (on that precise moment) which is the value of the CurrentCultureUI?

Comment: @SebastianInones Thanks for replying Sebastian!! I can't debug on windows 7 computer, I just execute a build there. CurrentCultureUI on windows 10 computer while debugging has "{es-ES}" as its value. That's what I don't get, is it possible that the difference relies on windows 7 config? In that case I just want to understand why

Comment: I worked with *richTextBox.SpellCheck.* a long time ago and I don't recall facing that issue but mainly all the computer's OS were set to Spanish "{es-ES}" culture by default. My suggestion (quite probably not the best one) is trying to add some logging if you are not able to debug on Windows 7 (at least to have more information on what's going on under the hood).